# In Java, remove the first char of the string if it is , (comma)

Tags: java, string, replace

In Java, I have a String variable.

Sometimes the first character of the string is a comma `,`

I want to remove the first char only if it is a comma.

What is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 49):

Something like:

```
text = text.startsWith(",") ? text.substring(1) : text;
```

is pretty simple...

Comment: Jon, Thanks for quick help and it helped me.

Comment: @Nishant: No requirement for `trim()` is specified in the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah, right it was not asked in the question. What I was saying that after removing leading comma, one may want to trim it for leading/trailing spaces. I was just commenting an idea.

Comment: I don't understand it please can u elaborate @JonSkeet

Comment: Okay i didn't understand syntax but after digging i found it out and it's now clear. Nice answer @JonSkeet

Comment: If the string is variable-length, would you have to check that text _has_ a character at position 1?

EDIT: No. The docs say an exception is only thrown if beginIndex is _greater_ than the length of the string, but in this case it's equal to.

Answer (score 20):

I would use the `^` anchor together with `replaceFirst()`:

```
niceString = yourString.replaceFirst("^,", "");
```

Comment: Personally I'd stick with simple string manipulations that *don't* require regular expressions. You need to be aware that `replaceFirst` *takes* a regular expression, then remember that a caret is "start of string". I prefer to use regular expressions when you're dealing with patterns which *can't* easily be identified in a simple way otherwise.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I agree in principle, but in this case I think this is easier and more readable than using an `if` statement (or ternary statement). I guess it's a matter of preferences.

Comment: Keepil, Thanks for quick help and it helped me

Answer (score 2):

If you have commons-lang in your classpath, may have a look at [StringUtils.removeStart(String str, String remove)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#removeStart-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public String methodNoCharacter(String input, String character){

if(input!= null && input.trim().length() > 0)//exist
            if(input.startsWith(character))//if start with '_'
                return methodNoCharacter(input.substring(1));//recursive for sure!

        return input;

}
```